# How to add explicit declaration in gradle android

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$FOO"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$FOO"

compile "com.android.support:design:$BAR"
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$BAR"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$BAR"
```

I need to add explicit compile declarations in your build.gradle. 
This link says https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#installation 
to put this codes to avoid the conflicts . but Android studio says FOO,BAR is not found. Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOO` and `BAR` are just variables defined in a `.gradle` file.
You can call them as you want.

To use this kind of syntax you can define in your top-level `build.gradle` something like:

```
project.ext { 
    firebaseVersion = '11.2.0'
    supportLibraryVersion = '26.0.1'
}
```

and then use these variables in another part of your module `build.gradle` file, for example in the dependencies.

For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$firebaseVersion"
}
```

Or if you prefer to use `FOO` and `BAR`

```
project.ext { 
        FOO = '11.2.0'
        BAR = '26.0.1'
    }

 dependencies {
        compile "com.android.support:design:$BAR"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$FOO"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

These all constants are defined in `constants.gradle` file

Example of constants.gradle

```
project.ext {
    compileSdk = 26
    targetSdk = 26
    minSdk = 14

    buildTools = '26.0.1' 
    firebaseVersion = '11.2.0'
    supportLibraryVersion = '26.0.1'
    playServiesVersion = '11.2.0'
}
```

You have to add constants.gradle file directly under project directory and 
add

```
apply from: 'constants.gradle'
```

in `build.gradle` of project.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply from: 'constants.gradle'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get clear understanding ! please explain more what is FOO, BAR ?

Comment: @eagle foo and bar are the version numbers of library..as the library version changes we have to change this foo and  bar value e.g when firebase-auth library will be upgraded we will be changing these versions number